# How to prove $v(x+y)\geq $inf$(v(x),v(y))$ in Serre's *Local fields*?

Tags: number-theory, local-field

In Serre's *Local fields*, Chapter One, Section One. I have difficulty proving that $v(x+y)\geq $inf$(v(x),v(y))$. Here is my attempt. Take $x=\pi^{n_{1}}u$ and $y=\pi^{n_{2}}u'$, then assume that $n_{2}>n_{1}$, we have $\pi^{n_{1}}(u+\pi^{n_{2}-n_{1}}u')$. Consequently, $v(\pi^{n_{1}}u+\pi^{n_{2}}u')=\pi^{n_{1}}(u+\pi^{n_{2}-n_{1}}u')=v(\pi^{n_{1}})+v(u+\pi^{n_{2}-n_{1}}u')$. However, I fail to do any successful calculation about $v(u+\pi^{n_{2}-n_{1}}u')$. I think that I'm on the wrong path.

[image]

Comment: Just write $x=\pi^ma,y=\pi^nb$ and pull out $\pi^{\min(m,n)}$ in $x+y$.  Note that $A=v^{-1}(\mathbb{N})\cup\{0\}$.

Comment: $u+\pi^{n_{2}-n_{1}}u' \equiv u \pmod{\pi}$, so has valuation zero; this reduces you to the case where $n_1 = n_2$.

Comment: OK，thanks a lot! I get it.